# VMware: error- 'CPU disabled by guest operating system' after I move the Virtual Machine folder?

Tags: vmware

I found my VMware cost a lot of space.

I want to use the `compress` function in the VMware workstation, but I found my laptop's space is not enough.

So, I copied this folder into my portable disk.

After using squeeze in VMware workstation, I copied it back to my laptop.
But I got the below message:

> ```
> CPU disabled by guest operating system
> ```

I had tried all methods on google, but none of them worked.

I have used this virtual machine for a lot of time, it saved a lot of document

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using Ubuntu as the host operating system …

This sort of error is usually seen when the virtual machine has not been cleanly shut down and is being moved from one VMware installation (or version) to another. There are two *reasonable* possible solutions to try:

1. Reset the VM. If the virtual machine was copied in an “uncleanliness state, then you can sometimes resolve this by rebooting the VM (even if it says it is off).
2. Verify that your host OS has not received an update recently that has disabled  VTx/VTd.

If neither of these work, you will need to search for the solution on a VMware support site, as this doesn’t seem to be an Ubuntu-specific issue.

Also, make backups. If you don’t have backups of your files, then the files aren’t really that important. There’s no valid excuse for *not* ensuring you can continue to work in the event of a complete system explosion.